# Any suggestions on best arranging (android) project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am from Microsoft Visual Studio background and bit new to Android and Eclipse. I have started with one Android application which by now has just 4 activities and already the number of fragments, layouts, other java classes (POCO objects) are exploding and the project code base structure is clearly becoming a mess.

Any suggestions on Eclipse/Android way of making it easy to

1. Arrange things domain or vertical wise
2. Quickly find out which layout
   is referred by which activity or fragment (I can surely come up with
   conventions of my own, but want to know how the experts are doing
   this)

Thanks
Sandeep